# How can I format string in an array using shell script?

Tags: shell

I'm beginner at shell scripting and I'm having a little troubles with my code.

My goal is to have control on the size and the format of the numbers in my array *"mystring"*

```
#!/bin/bash
mystring="333,4444,333,333,4444,333,333"
expectedValue=4
addLeftZero () {
      if [ $myCount -eq $expectedValue ]
        then
            #the number has the correct size
         else
            #this is where I have to prepend "0" until the number has the expected lenght,
            #for example the number "333" will be "0333"
        fi
            #here i have to return the full array with the mods
    }
IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$mystring"
    for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
        myCount=${#i}
        addLeftZero $i
        return $i
    done
```

> *0333,4444,0333,0333,4444,0333,0333*

I have used `sed` command, but it seems like I need to edit it in a file, not directly in my code.

What command can I use to format my strings? Do am I using the function correctly? Do I have visibility of my variables? Do you know a
better way to reach my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to left-pad the numbers with zeroes, this can be done in a single command:

```
$ printf '%04d\n' "${ADDR[@]}"
0333
4444
0333
0333
4444
0333
0333
```

Here each number in your array is passed to `printf` as a separate argument - it takes care of the formatting for you.

Of course, whether this is suitable or not depends on how your plan on using these numbers.

As an aside, `return` is only for indicating whether a routine succeeded or not. As such, it only supports values from `0` to `255`. To output something from a function or command, use standard output/error.